# Thinking Sphinx and rails: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet' error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm using the thinking-sphinx gem with my project and have been running into this error. The setup and search all worked in development but once I tried to set it up on my production environment, I run into `ActionView::Template::Error: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'` when going to a view with the search method.

rake ts:index and rake ts:start both work. I verified that searchd is running on port 9312. for what it's worth I'm running 
- thinking-sphinx 3.1.2
- rails 3.2
- ruby 1.9.3

My thinking_sphinx.yml file looks like this:

```
production:
mysql41: 9312
pid_file: /shared/tmp/searchd.pid
indices_location: /shared/db/sphinx
configuration_file: /config/production.sphinx.conf
binlog_path: /shared/binlog
```

My production.sphinx.conf after index looks like this:

```
searchd
{
  listen = 127.0.0.1:9312:mysql41
  log = /shared/log/production.searchd.log
  query_log = /shared/log/production.searchd.query.log
  pid_file = /shared/tmp/searchd.pid
  workers = threads
  binlog_path = /shared/binlog
}
```

Tried a few solutions that I found online but haven't been able to bypass this error yet. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you confirm which version of Thinking Sphinx you're using? Thinking Sphinx v3.x uses the MySQL protocol to connect to Sphinx, but v2.x does not, so this error doesn't make sense if you're using v2.0.12.

Comment: Also: does the searchd process exist on your production machine? There should be at least two for the given configuration file (the master process and then one worker per Ruby process that's using Sphinx).

Comment: Hi pat, thanks for the reply. Sorry I was reading the TS version from the wrong place, it's 3.1.2. In regards to your 2nd question, when i do a ps aux on the server i don't see any searchd processes, but port 9312 is listening for searchd.

Comment: Hmm, `ps aux | grep searchd` doesn't return anything? How are you sure that 9312 is listening for a connection? If there's clearly a process using that port, can you confirm what that process is?

Comment: Hey pat, after reading your comment I looked into the processes some more. It looks like the config file was pointing to 9213 but that port was already in use by a different searchd process from another app. I just assumed it was my searchd that was running on it. I switched to a new port and started up searchd on that one and changed the production.conf file to match, now it connects! Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction here, kind of an odd case.

Comment: Good to know it's all working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Running the command:

```
bundle exec rake ts:rebuild
```

worked for me.